# How to install vue.js inside a repository?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm

I have a project with a backend and frontend repository.
The frontend utilizes vue.js.

Now, I can easily clone the git repository onto my local machine. There I need to run it. 
To do this, I first need to set up vue.js inside the repository...somehow, I guess.
The repository doesnt have any node or npm or whatever stuff in it. I need to install this myself, locally (I guess this was done to protect the repository from growing too big).

I learnt on the vue.js official sites how to create a new project, but in this case, I'm working in an existing project, right? So how do I get vue.js into an existing project. 
Its vue-cli based btw., so I need to install vue-cli as well (or rather use the vue-cli version of vue.js)

Comment: What is the current framework of your FED? What is the project structure?

Comment: found the answer, thanks @tomerpacific

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the answer myself.

First, vue cli needs to be installed locally. So inside cmd cd to your local repository and execute:

```
npm install vue-cli
```

After this, install the serve functionality like this:

```
npm install -g serve
```

and then you can just do:

```
serve
```

And you get something like this on your cmd:

```
   │   Serving!                                        │
   │                                                   │
   │   - Local:            http://localhost:5000       │
   │   - On Your Network:  http://172.21.128.28:5000   │
   │                                                   │
   │   Copied local address to clipboard!              │
```

Optionally, you can also first build your project and then serve your dist, so after install your serve functionality, first do:

```
npm run build
```

and then

```
serve -s dist
```

and you should be fine. You can read about some of this stuff here too:
https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html#general-guidelines